# Make validation error message go away when the user focuses back into the input field

Tags: angular

Email must be valid email is displayed when the user enters the wrong email and moves out of the input field but as soon he moves inside the input field to correct the mistake the message doesn't go away.

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.touched">
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.errors.email" data-tip="Email must 
    be a valid email address"></div>
    </div>
```

ts

```
 email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
```

Comment: You can add a flag and change it whenever the user focuses on the input and show the message with the same flag. Look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3efprr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)..!

Comment: @RohitSharma, first, it's better put your code (the links can be broke in a future), second, use the "safe operator" registerForm.controls.email.errors?.email to avoid errors

Answer (score 1):

You can mark as untouched when focus control. See the [forked stackblitz of @Rohit Shama](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eafeuf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="container my-5 py-5">
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"
                  formControlName="email" 
                  <!--in focus, mark as untouched-->
                  (focus)="registerForm.controls.email.markAsUntouched()"  />
        <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.touched">
           <!--IMPORTANT: use safe operator in errors.email-->
          <span *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.errors?.email">
            Email must be a valid email address
          </span>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

::gulps:: it's the same answer than De Wet van As (sorry, I did'nt want "pirate" an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Even if the user moves again to correct the mistake, the value is still invalid and hence the error. The validation error message vanishes only after he changes the value and make it a valid one

Comment: yea i was asking this coz i show the message above the input field so its bad user exp. if he interacts with the input field and the message doesnt go away

Answer (score 0):

As @dileepkumar mentioned, the email value is still invalid and the message is still expected. If you really want to change the behaviour you can do it by marking the field as untouched when focusing the input as follows:

// html

```
<input [formControl]="email" (focus)="focusEmailInput()" />
```

// ts

```
focusEmailInput()
{
    this.regsiterForm.controls.get('email').markAsUnctouched();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.touched">
```

use this:

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.invalid">
```

and then display your error messages there.